# await in javascript for of loop using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

is there anything wrong with my code? i use express and mongoose

```
router.get('/c/:hashtoken', validateEmailToken, catchAsync(async(req,res)=>{
    const hashtoken = req.params.hashtoken
    const hashtoken2 = createHash('sha256').update(hashtoken).digest('hex')
    const realHashTokens = await EmailToken.find({hashtoken2})
    if(realHashTokens.length===0){
        req.flash('error','Incorrect email verification token or Your account has been activated')
        return res.redirect('/')
    }
    const toDeleteTokenId = []
    for(let realHashToken of realHashTokens){
        let theUser = await User.findById(realHashToken.user)
        theUser.active = true
        await theUser.save()
        toDeleteTokenId.push(realHashToken._id)
    }
    for (let theId of toDeleteTokenId){
        await EmailToken.findByIdAndDelete(theId)
    }
    req.flash('success','Success! Your account has been activated')
    return res.redirect('/')
}))
```

the page has never responded. it keeps loading, but user becomes active if i checked in the database

Comment: Is this an Ajax call?  Or a URL typed into the browser that makes this request.  Ajax calls do not cause the browser to change the page they are displaying unless you specifically write the client-side receiving Javascript to look for a 302 status and set `window.location` to a new page.

Comment: hello @jfriend00 , it's a url typed into the browser. user clicks this link from their email

Comment: Well, then I'd say put a `try/catch` in your function so you can detect any of the `await` statements that reject.  You currently have NO error handling for any of them.

Comment: it's in the catchAsync function. it's a wrapper for try catch

Comment: func => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        func(req, res, next).catch(err=>{next(err)});
    }
}

Comment: Then, go to the network tab in the Chrome browser and watch what happens when this request is sent to the server - to see if you get any response back.

Comment: there's no response, it's blank in the response tab because it keeps loadding

Comment: Then, trace through your server-side function and watch every line in the debugger.  If you don't know how to do that, learn.  If you don't want to learn, then put a `console.log()` statement between every line of code in that request handler so you can see exactly what it is and isn't doing.  Come on here - this is basic debugging - it's how you solve problems like this.  We can't do it for you - you have to do it yourself.

Comment: before this line ....    await theUser.save()    , it still prints to the terminal that user.active is true but after that line, no console.log statement run or printed to the terminal

Comment: Then, that `theUser.save()` promise is rejecting and sending your code to your error handler which is apparently not working properly or whatever it's doing is not getting back to the browser in the way you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Set an error handler or wrap in try/catch.
Also add more debug statments.

```js
router.get('/c/:hashtoken', validateEmailToken, catchAsync(async(req,res)=>{
try {
    console.log('request received')
    const hashtoken = req.params.hashtoken
    const hashtoken2 = createHash('sha256').update(hashtoken).digest('hex')
    console.log('finding token')
    const realHashTokens = await EmailToken.find({hashtoken2})
    if(realHashTokens.length===0){
        req.flash('error','Incorrect email verification token or Your account has been activated')
        return res.redirect('/')
    }
    const toDeleteTokenId = []
    console.log('finding user')
    for(let realHashToken of realHashTokens){
        let theUser = await User.findById(realHashToken.user)
        theUser.active = true
        await theUser.save()
        toDeleteTokenId.push(realHashToken._id)
    }
    console.log('deleting')
    for (let theId of toDeleteTokenId){
        await EmailToken.findByIdAndDelete(theId)
    }
    console.log('completed - redirecting')
    req.flash('success','Success! Your account has been activated')
    return res.redirect('/')
}
 catch(e) {
   console.error(e)
   // res.sendStatus(500)
   req.flash('error', e.message)
   return res.redirect('/')
}
}))
```

Comment: it's still doesn't print anything to my console

Comment: As the OP has said, `catchAsync()` which wraps all this is supposed to be doing the error handling.

Comment: But if the problem is with catchasync, the response wont get sent; this takes that out of the equation for debugging, to ensure all branches call res.redirect.

Comment: @Ben next step is to see where the code is stalling, so i will add debug statements to figure out where the bottleneck is.  One of your async is not living up to it's promise...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. the User model in this code has post mongoose middleware and within that function, I call next() even though there's no other post middleware after that so the server responds with long responds and the page keeps loading.